# Permissions on mounted drive not able to be changed

Tags: mount, permissions

So I have 4 2TB drives mounted as /media/Media1 , /media/Media2 , /media/Media3 , /media/Media4. /media I have changed permissions on to 775 root root 4096, but it will not let me change it on any of my 4 drives. The permissions on them are 777 root root 4096. I am wanting to change all four drives to 775 permissions. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo chmod -R 775 /media/Media1`